# Create SSO using SFAuthenticationSession in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, sfsafariviewcontroller, sfauthenticationsession

I'm working on two iOS applications that share the same keychain tokens which they receive when the user logs-in in either of the apps by entering his username and password in a web view. The tokens saved saved in the keychain, are time limited for a few hours/days - they are being refreshed when the user uses the app and makes request/enters items which are being opened in a browser.

Up until the release of iOS 11, the web view in the app was a SFSafariViewController instance and it was very convenient because it shared the cookies between the apps and once a user logged-in in a browser in one app, he would automatically be logged-in in the other app, thus achieving an SSO experience.

In iOS 11, the behavior of SFSafariViewController changed, and it no longer shares the cookies between different SFSafariViewController instances in my two apps. Instead, Apple wants us to use SFAuthenticationSession to achieve the same behavior.

In my app, I have a table of about 50 rows, almost all of them open a different URL in SFSafariViewController. So now, in iOS 11, I need to create a new instance of SFAuthenticationSession every time (the URL cannot be changed once the instance was created), and in order to actually show the web view, I need to invoke the start() method on this instance. However, this method can only be invoked once on the same instance (otherwise it will return 'false' and do nothing), and every time it is being invoked, it pops the notification that "myapp" wants to use "mydomain.com" to sign in. 
So it means that my users see this alert message on every tap on a row in the table.

Is there a way to make my app show the consent alert message only once, e.g. on the first time or something? I want my users to have an SSO experience in my two apps, that's why I used SFSafariViewController in the first place, but I don't want them to see this annoying alert on every tap they make in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way of having the alert message only show once using `SFAuthenticationSession`, we are experiencing the same issue on our apps.

I along with many others have filed a bug regarding this to Apple, asking them to show it only once like you suggested. The end of [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/120) discusses the alert.